# What functions can be considered as distributions?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have the following functions:

- $e^{2x} $
- $e^{-2x} $
- $e^{2x}H(x)$
- $e^{-2x}H(x)$
- $e^{\sin x}$
- $(x^2-1)^3$,

where $H$ is the Heaviside function. The question is - which of these functions can be considered as distributions? Clearly $e^{\pm 2x}$ grow way too fast as $x$ tends to $\pm \infty$. For the same reason, $e^{2}H(x)$ should be disqualified. It can be shown $e^{-2x}H(x) \in L^1_{\text{loc}}({\Omega})$ since $\int_{K \cap[0,+\infty]}|e^{-2x}| dx \leq \dfrac{1}{2}<+\infty$ for every compact $K \subset \Omega$. Since $|e^{\sin x}| =e^{\sin x}\leq e$ we conclude it is locally integrable and so it makes the list. It is pretty obvious $(x^2-1)^3\in \mathcal{D'}$ since it's in $\mathcal{P_6}$.

> **Question 1**: Are my arguments sound? Why not?
>
> **Question 2**: Is there a more general test to determine if a function can be considered as a distribution?

Comment: Any locally integrable function can be seen as a distribution. You maybe mean tempered distributions?

Comment: Well my book only stated "distributions", however it might be understood to mean tempered distributions. Are all tempered functions at most polynomially growing?